# Remove end-ticks from D3.js axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using (the excellent) D3.js to generate some plots, and I can't find a way to remove the end ticks from the x and y axis.

Take the y-axis for example.

When the end tick value coincides with a label, I'm ok with having it.

But when the last round label is below the end of the plot, I get two ticks, one for the last rounded label and one above it at the end of the y-axis.

I don't want this end-tick visible, because I find the fact that it appears in less than the regular interval between labels distracting.

See here for an example of what I'm describing, the ticks at `0` and `15` are the end ticks:

```
15 ─┐ 
    | 
10 _| 
    |
5  _|
    |
0  ─┤──────
```

Any tips?

P.S As a response suggested, I could set the ticks explicitly. But I like the convenience of the implicit generated ticks, just don't want unlabelled ticks to pollute the axis. So an ideal solution (if exists) would also take than into account.

Comment: **Working solution for D3 v5.9.2:** (1) Wrap `yAxis` in a `g` and **call** it: `svg.append("g").attr("id", "yAxisG").call(yAxis)`; (2) Remove is the first `<path>` element from the axis group: `d3.select("g#yAxisG").select("path").remove();`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`axis.tick*` functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks) can help you there. You have a number of possibilities to prevent the behaviour you're describing. You could set the ticks explicitly using the `tickValues()` function. Or you could set the size of the end ticks to 0 using `tickSize()`. You can also control the underlying scale using the `ticks()` function.

Depending on your particular scenario, one of these options may make more sense than the others.

Comment: Thanks, but I should probably clarify that I also want the implicit tick behaviour (if possible), instead of explicitly setting them just to bypass the end-tick issue.

Comment: Then have a look at `tickSize()`.

Comment: To remove only the ticks on the ends of the axis, use `axis.tickSizeOuter(0)` (d3 version 4.x) or `axis.outerTickSize(0)` (d3 version 3.x).

Answer (score 121):

For anyone who got to this question because all you want to do is remove the two end ticks from an axis, this will do the trick:

```
.outerTickSize(0)
```

Add that to any axis call you make, such as:

```
d3.svg.axis().outerTickSize(0)
```

Comment: And with the new [modular `d3-axis`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickSizeOuter), use `tickSizeOuter()`.

Comment: From docs: *the “outer ticks” are not actually ticks but part of the domain path, and their position is determined by the associated scale’s domain extent. Thus, outer ticks may overlap with the first or last inner tick. An outer tick size of 0 suppresses the square ends of the domain path, instead producing a straight line.*

Answer (score 12):

In d3.js v4.x use `.tickSizeOuter(0)`, like:

```
self._leftAxis = d3.axisLeft(self._y)
      .tickSizeInner(3) // the inner ticks will be of size 3
      .tickSizeOuter(0); // the outer ones of 0 size
```

Note that the zero tick below is considered a inner on

[image]

This d3.js v4 doc: https://github.com/d3/d3-axis

Comment: Note that you should not use `nice(0)` on the scale or `tickSizeOuter(0)` is ignored

Answer (score 8):

If you want to just hide the bounding values and keep the implicit behavior in the middle, you can modify the axis `SVG` object just after you draw it

Say, here you draw/update your axis:

```
g.selectAll(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
```

Now g will contain `.tick` classed objects. each of them will refer to one tick value. You can select them and set visibility attribute:

```
d3.select(g.selectAll(".tick")[0][0]).attr("visibility","hidden");
```

Alternatively, you can address any specific tick by its value `d` or index `i`

```
g.selectAll(".tick")
    .each(function (d, i) {
        if ( d == 0 ) {
            this.remove();
        }
    });
```

Be careful with `.remove()` though. Sometimes the first value is removed already and it removes the second value on update. Visibility hidden is more reliable.

*credit to Ian & Denis at d3-js google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/LBxR_finiME*

Answer (score 3):

Remove end ticks using something like this: note tickSize(inner, outer)

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).
                tickSize(3, 0).orient("bottom").tickFormat( ... );
```

If you put outer param to 0 in tickSize(inner, outer) you will not get the outer ticks.

Answer (score 1):

I'not sure, what the outer tick size has to do with the first or last tick of an axis.

---

`tickSize` actually controls the length of the `<line>` element inside of the tick group. Therefore it deals with the distance between the `<text>` element of the tick and the axis **or** the length of helper lines starting at the tick positions, which depends on the orientation of the axis and where it has been moved to (via css `translate()`).

This is how a tick group looks like:

```
<g transform="translate(10,0)" style="opacity: 1;" class="tick">
   <line x2="0" y2="-15"></line>
   <text x="0" y="-18" style="text-anchor: middle;" dy="0em">0.0</text>
</g>
```

Now you can control the `x2` and the `y2` attribute of the `<line>` element with the `tickSize` method. Here I'm using `tickSize(15, 0)` and `orientation('top')` for the x axis, which has been moved to the bottom of the chart. So the lables of the ticks project into the chart in a quite messy way.

Answer (score 1):

## Working solution for D3 v5.9.2:

1. After you declared `yAxis` and set the attributes, wrap it in a `g` and **call** it:

   ```
    svg.append("g").attr("id", "yAxisG").call(yAxis);
   ```
2. Remove the first `<path>` element from the axis group:

   ```
    d3.select("g#yAxisG").select("path").remove();
   ```

Answer (score -1):

This will remove the whole axis. This does not answer the question posted.

Answer (score -5):

Just remove both axis:

```
d3.selectAll('.axis').remove();
```