# D3.js: Hide the last tick on an axis?

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3.js to draw an axis with ticks. I would like to hide only the last tick on the y-axis.

Maybe a picture will make it clearer. This is what my axis looks like at the moment - I'd like to **hide the "21" and its associated tick**.

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
  var yAxisScale = d3.svg.axis().orient("left");
  yAxisScale.scale(y_position);
  yAxisScale.ticks(20).tickFormat(function(d) { return d+1; });
  var yAxis = vis.selectAll("g.y.axis").data([1]);
```

Is there a way I can hide only the last tick, regardless of how many ticks there are on the y-axis?

I tried adding this line, but it doesn't work, even though the selectAll expression appears to return the right element.

```
d3.select(d3.selectAll("g.y.axis g")[0].pop()).style('opacity',  1e-6);
```

The opacity is still set to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should to take a look at axis.tickSize(). it allows you to set the size of the major, minor, and end ticks.

also see here for similar question:

[Remove end-ticks from D3.js axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669239/remove-end-ticks-from-d3-js-axis)

Comment: Thanks! Actually I ended up setting the values explicitly with `tickValues()` and that did the trick.