# D3: How to remove tick marks at the top and bottom of Y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

[image]

I can't figure out how to turn off these tick marks at the top and bottom of the y axis in a D3 chart. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's how I am generating the axis:

```
// Set the ranges
var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(2)
  .tickFormat(formatTime);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(2)
  .tickFormat(d3.format("$,"));
```

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help if you don't share your code.

Comment: In you axis generator, put this (if v4.x): `.tickSizeOuter(0)`.

Comment: Gerardo, I've tried adding that function but am apparently doing something wrong: 
     var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .tickSizeOuter(0)
       .scale(yScale)
       .orient("left")
       .ticks(2)
       .tickFormat(d3.format("$,"));```
I get the error `... tickSizeOuter is not a function...`

Comment: Because you're using v3. I wrote **v4** in my comment.

Comment: In v3 is `.outerTickSize(0)`. It has been so long since the last time I used v3 that I had to search the API to remember it.

Comment: See highest voted answer in [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669239/remove-end-ticks-from-d3-js-axis). In brief, you want to use `d3.svg.axis().outerTickSize(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The short of it is that you want to use the method `.outerTickSize()` and pass it a `0` value, like so:

`d3.svg.axis().outerTickSize(0)`

See the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickSizeOuter) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this script to remove all ticks on y axis.

```
d3.selectAll(".y.axis").selectAll(".tick").selectAll("line").remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

Better use CSS

```
.y.axis .tick line:first-child, 
.y.axis .tick line:last-child{
   opacity: 0;
}
```