# D3 tickSizeOuter(0) to remove end-ticks NOT working

Tags: d3.js

I'm following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669239/remove-end-ticks-from-d3-js-axis) to remove end ticks in my bar graph, as follows:

```
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale); 
yAxis.tickValues([0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]); 
yAxis.tickSizeOuter(0); // <--- This does not remove the end ticks
```

However, this does not remove the end ticks in the y-axis.

Now, when I enter this line of code:

```
yAxis.tickSize(0);
```

I am able to remove all the ticks on the y-axis.

Why isn't the `tickSizeOuter(0)` code working and how can I remove just the end-ticks?

Here is the version of d3 I am using with my Angular project:

```
"d3": "^5.9.1"
```

Comment: This is the standard way of removing the outer ticks. If this does not work for you, you should set up an executable demo showing the issue.

Comment: If `0` and `2500` are the values in your domain (that is, `[0, 2500]`), **you have no end ticks**.

Comment: **Working solution for D3 v5.9.2:** (1) Wrap `yAxis` in a `g` and **call** it: `svg.append("g").attr("id", "yAxisG").call(yAxis)`; (2) Remove the first `<path>` element from the group: `d3.select("g#yAxisG").select("path").remove();`

Answer (score 2):

yAxis.tickSizeOuter(0) remove outer ticks which means that y line is straight line, but it doesn't remove actual ticks (e.g. 0-). If you what that you should use something like:

```
  const tick_count = d3.selectAll("g.axis.axis--y .tick").size();
  d3.selectAll("g.axis.axis--y .tick")
    .each(function (d, i) {
      console.log(d,i)
      if ( i == 0 || i == tick_count-1) {
        this.remove();
      }
    });
```

Hope I understand correctly your misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 1):

## Working solution for D3 v5.9.2:

1. After you declared `yAxis` and set the attributes, wrap it in a `g` and **call** it:

   ```
   var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale); 
   yAxis.tickValues([0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]);

   svg.append("g").attr("id", "yAxisG").call(yAxis);
   ```
2. Remove the first `<path>` element from the group:

   ```
   d3.select("g#yAxisG").select("path").remove();
   ```